# Get amplitude from MediaPlayer using Visualizer

Tags: android, audio, visualizer, amplitude, decibel

i've been reading another posts about calculate the amplitude in real time from a Mediaplayer, but i have no clear how to get a value useful for me. What i need is a linear amplitude value normalize between 0-100, but as i've watched in another posts they are performing a db calculation which has not much sense, cause they are not normalized to max 0dB value (from [How to calculate the audio amplitude in real time (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215289/how-to-calculate-the-audio-amplitude-in-real-time-android)):

```
double amplitude = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < audioData.length/2; i++) {
    double y = (audioData[i*2] | audioData[i*2+1] << 8) / 32768.0
    // depending on your endianness:
    // double y = (audioData[i*2]<<8 | audioData[i*2+1]) / 32768.0
    amplitude += Math.abs(y);
}
amplitude = amplitude / audioData.length / 2;
```

I've watched that for calculate de dB, i should do as below (from [How to compute decibel (dB) of Amplitude from Media Player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822314/how-to-compute-decibel-db-of-amplitude-from-media-player)
)

```
double sum=0;
for (int i = 0; i < audioData.length/2; i++) {
    double y = (audioData[i*2] | audioData[i*2+1] << 8) / 32768.0;
    sum += y * y;
}
double rms = Math.sqrt(sum / audioData.length/2);
dbAmp = 20.0*Math.log10(rms);
```

I've tried for that solution but the real time values are near to 0 but sometimes are over than 0, i mean, something between -Inifinit (no sound) to 1.2 (if i avoid 20.0* multiply) or anything else from than order. Anyway, i'd like to obtain a normalized value [0-100], not a dB value.

Comment: How did you solve this?